# MySQL Start Error

Tags: mysql, linux, shell

I am trying to install MySQL 5.6.17 on Ubuntu Linux and I am having difficulties doing so. I opened the MySQL Reference and opened "Installing MySQL on Unix/Linux Using Generic Binaries". I followed the following step:

```
shell> groupadd mysql

shell> useradd -r -g mysql mysql

shell> cd /usr/local

shell> tar zxvf /path/to/mysql-VERSION-OS.tar.gz

shell> ln -s full-path-to-mysql-VERSION-OS mysql

shell> cd mysql

shell> chown -R mysql .

shell> chgrp -R mysql .

shell> scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql

shell> chown -R root .

shell> chown -R mysql data

shell> bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql &

//Next command is optional

shell> cp support-files/mysql.server /etc/init.d/mysql.server
```

After that when I try to start MySQL using `/etc/init.d/mysql.server start` I get the following error:

```
Couldn't find MySQL server (/usr/bin/mysqld_safe)
```

I looked in `/usr/bin` and I found mysqld_safe. Any suggestions on how to fix that problem. Please reply with a detailed solution.

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have installed Mysql in "/usr/local" and init script is looking for binaries in "/usr"

Change the "basedir" in /etc/init.d/mysql.server to :

basedir=/usr/local

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you found `/usr/bin/mysqld_safe` suggests that MySQL in some shape or form was preinstalled on your OS. This can cause some confusion, in particular due to location of config files.

So for instance, on some versions of Ubuntu, the packages `mysql-common` is pre-installed, which means you might have an `/etc/mysql/my.conf` file with some defaults in it. When you install from the tar file to `/usr/local`, follow the INSTALL-BINARIES (or equivalent) instructions, and try to start `/etc/init.d/mysql.server start` you might get errors as the one you report ("Couldn't find MySQL server (/usr/bin/mysqld_safe)"), because the default configuration in `/etc/init.d/mysql.server` and any `/etc/my.cnf` that you created (optional step during install) is getting over-ridden by a setting in the OS installed `/etc/mysql/my.conf`. **Note that this might happen even if you change the values in `/etc/init.d/mysql.server` and/or `/etc/my.cnf`**.

One way out is to merge `/etc/my.cnf` and /etc/mysql/my.cnf into a single file at one of these locations, with the correct defaults that you wish to use.